# Can UFT/QTP switch system locale?

Tags: windows, locale, qtp, hp-uft

I have a test case which requires me to first change the system's locale and then start the test. I want to automate the process of changing the system locale with qtp/uft, is that possible?

Can UFT/QTP automate the change of the system locale on a window machine?

Comment: Hi. I've never had to work with it, but after a brief research I found [this article](http://www.advancedqtp.com/internationalization/) and [this other article](http://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinoscript/getting_and_setting_locale/) that might help you

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  At the start (or other appropriate point) of your test use `SetLocale(lcid)` like this:

```
SetLocale("en-gb") ' sets locale to UK
SetLocale("en-us") ' sets locale to US
SetLocale("de")    ' sets locale to Germany
```

[This link](http://ss64.com/locale.html) will show you the various `lcid`s available for use

Comment: doesn't set local just set the script engine to the locale? I want to set the system's locale. Change the language on windows

Comment: I found a way to do this but it looks like the change requires logging off then on again, which would obviously halt your script: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-change-the-system-39f06b1c

Answer (score 0):

The WINAPI [SetThreadLocale](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be a way of doing that, with the restriction that only the processes started by UFT will inherit it (You need to make sure that your AUT is a child process of UFT). You can use WINAPI functions via the Extern.Declare headers.

We should not forget that such practices are considered malware - doesn't matter the honest purpose - so if you really want to stay clean, make your work transparent, comply to security rules; and most of all, you have UFT - do it via the GUI as the normal user would do it.